# Cannot read property 'send' of undefined(Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Sorry to bother you guys. I wrote a code but i think this code has problems because I am new to js and discord.js.
Appreciate any help
(Also ive looked some other questions but i couldnt find an example like mine)

````js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    name: "ping",
    description: "Returns latency and API ping",
    execute: 
    async (client, message, args) => 
    {
        try
        {
        const msg = await message.channel.send(` Pinging....`);

        msg.edit(` Pong!
        latency ${Math.floor(msg.createdTimestap - message.createdTimestap)}ms
        API latency ${Math.round(client.ping)}ms`);
        }catch(e){console.log(e)}```

    }
}
````

Here is the console:

```
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\berke\Desktop\RedBot\commands\ping.js:10:43)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\berke\Desktop\RedBot\bot.js:77:35)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\berke\Desktop\RedBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\berke\Desktop\RedBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\berke\Desktop\RedBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\berke\Desktop\RedBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\berke\Desktop\RedBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\berke\Desktop\RedBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

Comment: Error says exactly what is the problem. For some reasons `message.channel` is null.

Comment: As the error states: the `channel` property is `undefined`, for whatever reason. If you don't want your app to break, you can check if the `channel` object property is defined and then use its keys like this: `const msg = await (message.channel && message.channel.send(' Pinging....'));`

Comment: Are you passing the right thing to the `message` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

As the commenters have pointed out, there is no channel property on the message you are receiving in the function.

You can debug your application and see what the value of the parameters are at execution time, or you can `console.log()` them and just test it out to get a better understanding of what is happening.

If you're following the guides on [Discord.js](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/dynamic-commands.html#dynamically-executing-commands)' documentation, you might want to check out this [repository](https://github.com/discordjs/guide/blob/master/code-samples/command-handling/dynamic-commands/12/index.js) which shows a working example of dynamically executing commands.

For the purposes of stackoverflow I'll paste the relevant code from that repo below:

`index.js`

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

    try {
        client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
});
```

`commands/ping.js`

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'Ping!',
    execute(message) {
        message.channel.send('Pong.');
    }
```

`config.json`

```json
{
    "prefix": "!",
    "token": "your-token-goes-here"
}
```